How to get statistics only for complete iterations of samplers in a thread group?
I have a thread group that consists of several samplers. I run a test on this thread group with a finite thread lifetime. The result I see in the aggregate report is that the number of samples run by each sampler decreases from top to bottom, something like this:
Label        #Samples     Average ...(and so on)
Sampler1     113           97
Sampler2     113           54
Sampler3     112          213
Sampler4     111          219
...
Sampler8     110           80
Sampler9     110           57
TOTAL        999          104

In this case, I have 110 complete iterations from Sampler1 to Sampler9. I understand that the statistics at the end are for all the samples that have gone through all the samplers, but I would like to see those for just these 110 complete iterations. Can this be done?

You can use Excel or equivalent to filter the "unwanted" results from JMeter .jtl results file (which is basically a CSV file) prior to opening it in Aggregate Report listener.
Alternatively instead of setting the desired test duration in the Thread Group you could use While Controller for this, example __groovy() function you can use as the While Controller's condition:
${__groovy((System.currentTimeMillis() - (vars.get('TESTSTART.MS') as long)) < your-desired-test-duration-in-millisecons-here,)}

In this case all While Controller's child Samplers will be executed equal amount of times.
